# pl/sql: сравнение строк, которые могут быть null

Tags: sql, oracle

Пишу простой запрос, например:

```
select distinct a.*,
from   test_table a
where  1=1
and    a.code = '11111'
and    a.priority = (
         select min(priority)
         from   kdi_t_activate)
```

заметил, что если подзапрос `select min(priority) from kdi_t_activate` выдаст `null`, то `a.priority = (select min(priority) from kdi_t_activate)` будет как `null = null`, но почему-то это уравнение неверное (условие не срабатывает и в результате запроса 0 строк).

Если сделать костыль в `where` в виде:

```
and case 
      when a.priority is null then '0' 
      else a.priority 
    end =
        case 
          when (select min(priority) from   kdi_t_activate) is null then '0' 
          else (select min(priority) from kdi_t_activate) 
        end
```

то все срабатывает. Есть ли какой-нибудь более оптимальный путь, чтобы при сравнении двух null-овых значений результат сравнение был true?

Извиняюсь, если написал непонятно - исправлю.

Comment: в oracle `null не равно null`. Либо оборачивать в nvl либо использовать фнукции `is null` или `is not null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
select distinct a.*,
from   test_table a
where  1=1
and    a.code = '11111'
and    NVL(a.priority, '-1') = NVL((select min(priority) from kdi_t_activate), '-1')
```

При этом вместо '-1' надо поставить заведомо невозможное значение для столбца priority.

Это вполне нормальное решение. Если расписывать условия с IS NULL через OR - по скорости будет работать так же, но менее читаемо.

Comment: благодарю, действительно хорошая альтернатива громоздкому `case when ...`